# Minecraft won't run if I change the ram limits

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I have a  computer with 8GB of ram. With this I can play with a distance of **16** chunks (200+ fps), and now I want to try to play with **far** distance. However, I need to increase the RAM amount in the profile properties tab. 
When I set the ram to `2G`, the game won't run.

Java settings for the profile:
    `javaw -Xmx2048 -Xms1024`

I have installed 64-bit java in my computer.

**Why I can't set more RAM?**

If it is useful:
The profile is vannilla minecraft (no mods).
It doesn't start.

Comment: What happens when it doesn't run? Do you get an error message or crash dump? What does it say?

Comment: @fredley Nothing shows up, just the game won't run.

Comment: How does it "not run"? Does it cease running mid-load, or does it not even start?

Comment: @user1337 It doesn't start.

Comment: Are we talking about a clean MC, or modded?

Comment: @user1337 Clean.

Comment: Does it run if you roll back the memory settings to the defaults?  I assume you are manipulating the -xms and -xmx variables?

Comment: @MadMAxJr Yes. If I set the settings to default, the game can run. But if I change them to higher values, the game won't start.

Comment: Can you please share what you are setting the values at when it does not run?

Comment: @MadMAxJr Done.

Comment: Sorry for the constant questions, just going through the standard troubleshooting stuff to get facts.  Do you have just the 64 bit JVM or do you have both 32 and 64 bit JVMs installed?

Comment: @MadMAxJr Don't worry for the comments. Just Java 64.

Comment: I'm not sure Java understands these numbers by themselves. Try adding `M` behind the numbers to indicate that you mean Megabytes, i.e. `-Xmx2048M -Xms1024M`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the launcher is using 32-bit Java instead. If you have the correct Java version installed, it should look like this:

[image: Minecraft Launcher - Profile Editor Screenshot]

where `Executable` option points to the 64-bit Java executable file (either `java.exe` or `javaw.exe`).

Comment: Maybe that's the problem. I'll look it.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to set the RAM to 2 Gigabytes, try typing "-Xmx2G" instead. If you ever seem to need more RAM for any reason, you can add more to the number; for example, typing "-Xmx3G" for 3 Gigabytes, "-Xmx4G" for 4 gigabytes, and so on.